# PHP mpdf handling block level elements inside table

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mpdf library to generate PDF from HTML.I came across the limitation of mpdf that we cannot use block level elements inside table.Is there any possible way to make mpdf work with following code?. I tried span instead of p but its not act like block level elements.

```
<table style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <p style="text-align:left;font-size:14px;font-family:Arial;padding-left:105px;">Some text</p>
                        <p style="text-align:left;font-weight:normal;font-size:14px;font-family:Arial;padding-left:125px;">Some text Some text Some text </p>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The styles of Block level elements inside table,td won't reflect in PDF.I have fixed above issue with using another table by following.Hope it will help someone.

```
        <table style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <table>
                      <tr>
                       <td style="text-align:left;font-size:14px;font-family:Arial;padding-left:105px;">
                       Some text
                       </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                       <td style="text-align:left;font-weight:normal;font-size:14px;font-family:Arial;padding-left:125px;">
                       Some text Some text Some text
                       </td>                          
                      </tr>
                    </table>                        
                  </td>
                </tr>
          </table>
```